# Wrong encoding with fromJSON of jsonlite library

Tags: r, encoding, character-encoding, rjson, jsonlite

I have converted a json data from a .json file to an R object with using `fromJSON()` of [jsonlite](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html) library like this:

```
library(jsonlite)   
jsonR<-fromJSON(txt="data.json")
```

If I explore the stringed values of the `jsonR` object I meet some strange sequences of chars.

For example if a string value of the original "data.json" was  then R read it as \xf0\u009f\u0098©. And when I write this value back to file with `cat()` it becomes < f0>.

Can anyone suggest how one is supposed to do for keeping the correct original encoding while converting?

Answer (score 0):

There must be something wrong with your requested URL. If that's not the problem, try it with the following packages:
`library(RCurl)` or `library(RJSONIO)`